# NSInteger returning Big Values 6005

Tags: ios

I am using a simple picker view, where i need to check which row has been selected, But the value of didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row, row is coming out to be 6005 which is some really big value. How do i convert this to its exact value

below is the code for details. row value is printing out as 6005.

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


       NSLog(@"ROW IS %d", row);



    }
```

Please can any one help out with this, truly appreciate your help.

Thanks 
djrecker

Comment: whats wrong with 6005? how many rows do you have?

Comment: post some code first - can't really say if 6005 is valid or not with the code you currently have.

Comment: Try NSLog(@"ROW IS %i",row);

Comment: just have 50 rows in the picker, also using %i is still giving the same results.

Comment: google print nsinteger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528670/how-to-print-a-nsinteger-value-from-an-nsmanagedobject-using-nslog

Comment: @SamBudda the problem there was that the user had an object and was treating it as an int value. This actually is an int (well, `long`). Not the same problem.