# block syntax for calling class method in AFNetworking2

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

This is a total noob question but I'm testing out AFNetworking2 specifically, the UIWebView+AFNetworking piece. But how do I call loadRequest. I have:

```
    NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];  //fine
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];  //find


   [self.myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest progress:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))^{ // do I need second carat?
        //NSLog(@"writing bytes %i", bytesWritten);  // how to get access to bytesWritten?
        NSLog(@"writing bytes");

    }....
```

but I want to NSLog the bytesWritten. Block syntax always throws me for a loop. Do I need the second carat in the call?

Here's a link to docs for the call: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Categories/UIWebView+AFNetworking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper syntax

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)){ 
    NSLog(@"writing bytes %lu", (unsigned long)bytesWritten);
}];
```

### References:

- [Block Syntax](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/) (note that the return type can be omitted and it's inferred by the block implementation)
- [How to print a NSInteger value from an NSManagedObject using NSLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528670/how-to-print-a-nsinteger-value-from-an-nsmanagedobject-using-nslog)

Answer (score 1):

A "second carat" would be approx. 400 milligrams. The word you are looking for is "caret".

---

This is how you pass in a literal block:

```
[Foo doStuff:^(T1 arg1, T2 arg2) {
    // and this is how you use the arguments:
    NSLog(@"Arg 2: %@", arg2);
}];
```

Comment: the block return type is missing (it can be implicit when `void`, though)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella True. But can't it be implicit in any other case, when it can be deduced? (Let me check that in the meantime.)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yay, awesome.

Comment: thanks for answer; the syntax is so cryptic; appreciate the help

Comment: @timpone the syntax looks weird, but it's actually consistent with C declaration rules. Here's a nice article about it: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/

Comment: thx for article @GabrielePetronella - will read through it (prob like 10 times)